# How to add a react-native expo user login in the app

Tags: react-native, expo

I basically made a login page which could grab user/password from the text input, but if I want to use these to get auth from my website which has a REST API, where should I start it, is any lib that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how deeply you want to make. So I'll guess your concerning.

1. If you want to just send and get response from server

- You can use fetch() method in js. Luckily react-native have documentation. https://reactnative.dev/docs/network Look this documents. React-Native have own fetch method for communicating with server.

2. If you want to manage state of your client-side data

- Redux : You might probably hear this one. you can include redux in your package. we can use redux in react-natvie not only react. I just googled articles. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-react-native-redux
- MobX : Redux is pretty much complicate way to deal with state. So If you need simple things. you can try MobX. try this one. (also googled) https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/08/mobx-state-manager-react-native-applications/

Hope this idea helps you.
Best regards.

Comment: Thank you, I am a back-end programmer, my boss gave me two months to make a simple mobile phone APP.

Comment: So sorry to hear that. I recommend analyze repos like this.  It helps you build app from nothing. https://github.com/thecodingmachine/react-native-boilerplate